# Using masks and transparency

Tags: mask

I am new to video editing. I am trying to use layers, transparency and masks in order to achieve the following:

I want to have a opaque background with a shape, say a circle, that would be transparent and show some video in it, e.g. someone presenting a given topic.

I am not sure how to go about implementing this with iMovie. Is it possible at all? If not, what other software could achieve this? Also, what is the appropriate vocabulary/lingo that corresponds to what I am describing?